# Searching table efficiently for specific phrase

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to search an entire column for a specific phrase. I know I can use the SQL statement of `SELECT description FROM questions WHERE description LIKE '%what%' AND description LIKE '%if%'` to search for the phrase "What if" in the description column. My problem is that if I have a million entries, then searching through the column might take a while.

Is there a way to search through an entire column efficiently to check if a specific phrase exists?

Comment: Configure a full text index on the column.

Comment: You'll need to create index for table.

Answer (score 0):

[Full text search](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-mysql-full-text-search.aspx) provides exactly what you want. By creating a text index for your search column, mysql will look for your phrase in that column efficiently, and will return to you a score based match for your phrase, which you can effectively use to get your result.